# Respawn corosync/pacemaker automatically when it is killed

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, upstart, pacemaker, corosync

How to recover Corosync/Pacemaker if it is killed using `"kill -9 <corosync-pid>"`.

Are there any steps needs to be done to bring the corosync service up and running automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Create an upstart script in /etc/init/corosync.conf and /etc/init/pacemaker.conf with respawn option will solve the problem.

Upstart scripts can be found here.

**Corosync:** https://github.com/corosync/corosync/blob/master/init/corosync.conf.in

**Pacemaker:** https://github.com/ClusterLabs/pacemaker/blob/master/mcp/pacemaker.upstart.in